# php mail отправка на 2 и более письма

Tags: php, email

Есть код:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']!="") {
    $name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 1000); 
    $name_bl = '<div style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700;">Имя: <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: 400;">'.$name.'</span></div>';
} else {
    $name = '';
    $name_bl = '';
}
if(isset($_POST['tel']) && $_POST['tel']!="") {
    $tel = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 1000);
    $tel_bl = '<div style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700;">Телефон: <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: 400;">'.$tel.'</span></div>';
} else {
    $tel = '';
    $tel_bl = '';
}   
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!="") {
    $email = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 1000);
    $email_bl = '<div style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700;">E-mail: <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: 400;">'.$email.'</span></div>';
} else {
    $email = '';
    $email_bl = '';
}
$title = 'Заголовок';
$to = 'иии@mail.ru';

require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->setFrom($to);
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->msgHTML('
    <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px;">'.$title.'</div>
    '.$name_bl.'
    '.$tel_bl.'
    '.$email_bl.'
');
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "error"; die();
} else {
    echo "ok";
}
```

?>

Как сделать так что бы письмо отправлялось нескольким адресатам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
$mail->addAddress($to);
```

использовать несколько

```
$mail->addBCC($to1);
$mail->addBCC($to2);
$mail->addBCC($to3);
```

так вы добавите скрытые копии, и получатели не увидят кому еще ушли письма.

Comment: Вообще полезно посмотреть на такие поля как To, CC и BCC 
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-to-and-cc-in-email